# WIX: Unable to Customise Member's Area page based on User's Login ID

Tags: velo

I am trying to make a WIX page where users can log in and access a page where they can update their profile. However, when I try to do this, I am only able to display a particular single member's information on the update profile page, despite trying to change the filter settings of the dataset to "Filter by Logged-In User". I've also tried changing site permissions to allow who can read/write to the database. I've looked everywhere but can't find anything on the WIX help page.

I feel that this should be something that is fairly simple to implement, but for some reason it does not work.